# Mockito returnsFirstArg() doesn't work with generic first arg

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock, matcher

> **EDIT**: I've finally created an [issue](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1071) on mockito github project.

I'm trying to mock the typed method `getNameElement` of Interface `RoomGeneralService` to return the first arg, using Mockito `AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg` functionality:

**Interface to mock**:

```
interface PrimaryKeyElement<T> {
   public String getNameElement(T primaryKey);
}

interface RoomGeneralService extends PrimaryKeyElement<String> {
   // ...
}
```

**My test** (note the imports)

```
import static org.mockito.AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SampleTest {

   @Mock
   RoomGeneralService roomGeneralService;

   @Test
   public void testFoo() throws Exception {
      when(roomGeneralService.getNameElement(anyString())).thenAnswer(returnsFirstArg());
      //...
   }
}
```

Also I've tried with other combinations, but without success so far:

```
when(roomGeneralService.getNameElement(Matchers.<String>any())).thenAnswer(returnsFirstArg());
doAnswer(returnsFirstArg()).when(roomGeneralService.getNameElement(anyString()));
doReturn(returnsFirstArg()).when(roomGeneralService.getNameElement(anyString()));
```

**Error received**:

> The reason for this error can be :
>   1. The wanted argument position is incorrect.
>   2. The answer is used on the wrong interaction.
>
> Position of the wanted argument is 0 and the possible argument indexes
>   for this method are :
>       [0] Object

**Workaround**:

I know I can create my own answer, and in fact it's working fine if instead of use `returnFirstArg()` I do something like this:

```
when(roomGeneralService.getNameElement(anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
   @Override
   public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
      return (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];
   }
});
```

But I would use `returnFirstArg()` as in the rest of my tests (tests look cleaner), as well as mocking is working fine if the method `getNameElement` would receive an `String` instead a `T` arg.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to open an issue ([#1071](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1071)) on mockito github project  and it has been fixed in version **2.8.29** (See the official [changelog](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/doc/release-notes/official.md)) Thanks to the Mockito team to solve it so quickly!

Quoting @ChristianSchwarz, here is a problem explanation:

> Mockito checks if the argument type is compatible with the return type
>   to make a misuse ot the API as soon as posible visible. In this case
>   the argument-type Object is inferred from the generic type T, due to
>   type erasure. Since Object is not a subtype of String Mockito throws
>   the exception you see.
>
> Solution: The issue can by fixed by inferring the argument-type of the
>   actual argument-instance. In case the argument-type is a primitive or
>   the arg is null Mockito must fallback and use the type provided by
>   method signature.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Mockito isn't smart enough to deduce that the parameter type will be bound to `String` in the parameterized subinterface.

You can override the method in the subinterface

```
interface RoomGeneralService extends PrimaryKeyElement<String> {
    @Override
    public String getNameElement(String primaryKey);
}
```

Mockito won't have to guess. It will clearly see `String` as the parameter type of the stubbed method.

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering. Unfortunately method overriding is not an option for the project. If Mockito cannot do that, I preffer continue with the workaround.

Comment: @troig You don't control the source code of these interfaces?

Comment: No, that's the issue. Thanks for your approach anyway.